# Does .prependTo() follow the jQuery chaining?

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-chaining, domexception, jquery-append

I'm making a project, and in some line, there's a check button that when checked it relocates it's parent to the bottom. Here's it's markup :

```
<div id="tasksWrapper">
    <div class="subTaskWrapper">
        <div class="subTask">
            <div class="subMarker"></div>
            <label class="subTaskLabel"></label>
            <div class="subHolder"></div>
            <div class="subOptions">
                <ul>
                    <li id="subInfo">Details</li>
                    <li id="subEdit">Edit</li>
                    <li id="subDelete">Delete</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="checkButton"></div>
            <div class="optTrigger"></div>
        </div>
        // more than one of that subTask divs ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's it's code :

```
$("#tasksWrapper").on("click", ".subTask .checkButton", function(){
    if($(this).parent().data("checked") == true){
        $(this).css("opacity", "0.2")
            .siblings(".optTrigger , .subHolder").show()
            .parent().data("checked",false);
    } else {
        $(this).css("opacity", "1.0")
            .siblings(".optTrigger , .subHolder").hide()
            .parent().data("checked",true).appendTo($(this).parent().parent());
    }

});
```

I want the `.subTask` div to be appended to `.subTaskWrapper` div, so in the `else` case i tried this first :

```
else {
        $(this).css("opacity", "1.0")
            .siblings(".optTrigger , .subHolder").hide()
            .parent().data("checked",true).appendTo($(this).parent());
    }
```

I thought `.appendTo` in this case will append `.subTask` div to the `.subTaskWrapper` div, but i got this error :

> Uncaught Error: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3

But when i added another `.parent()` to the `.appendTo($(this).parent())` , it worked, so it became

`.appendTo($(this).parent().parent())`

I want to know why this Exception is generated in the first case and how `.appendTo` is affected when it's located after `.parent()`, Does it append `.parent()` or just the original `$(this)` ?

Comment: You said that your code is working with `parent().parent()`. Don't fix what is not broken :). To confirm to yourself though why it is working that way try using debugging tools in your browser such as `console.log($(this))`, `console.log($(this).parent())`, `console.log($(this).parent().data("checked", true))`, etc. Also you are asking `Does .prependTo() follow the jQuery chaining?` but all your code relates to `appendTo()`, which is confusing.

Comment: I tried to use `console.log()` but i want to place it instead of `.appendTo()` to know what's the current `$(this)`, but i think i can't do that in jQuery, any help putting `.console.log()` in the position of `appendTo()` would be appreciated.

Comment: Within your `else` just place the console log for each element you are "chaining" and watch the console. For example place console log into your else statement for : `$(this)`,  `$(this).css("opacity", "1.0")`, `$(this).css("opacity", "1.0").siblings(".optTrigger , .subHolder")`, `$(this).css("opacity", "1.0").siblings(".optTrigger , .subHolder").hide().parent()`, `$(this).css("opacity", "1.0").siblings(".optTrigger , .subHolder").hide().parent().data("checked",true)` and off course `$(this).parent()` and `$(this).parent().parent()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're appending an element to itself; that would explain the DOM hierarchy error.  If you strip out the core parts of the chain, the effect is:

```
$(this).parent().appendTo($(this).parent());
```

In other words:

```
$(this).css("opacity", "1.0")                 // $(this) refers to checkButton
    .siblings(".optTrigger , .subHolder")     // context is still checkButton
    .hide()
    .parent()                                 // context is now subTask
    .data("checked",true)                     // still subTask
    .appendTo($(this).parent());              // $(this).parent() is subTask
                               // so, this line says to append subTask to itself
```

Comment: Ah, so `$(this).parent()` that's inside `.appendTo()` refers to `.subTask` not `.subTaskWrapper` ? Then `.appendTo()` doesn't follow jQuery chaining ? Because i thought that `$(this)` inside `.appendTo()` refers to `.subTask`.

Comment: @Rafael no, I think that's normal chaining behavior -- chaining just means that each method call returns the same source object.

Comment: @Rafael: Instead of second guessing which element is where I think that all your questions can be answered with console.log outputs. See my comment on original question.

Comment: @Rafael `this` isn't related to chaining or JQuery.  The `this` context would never change just like that.